# iOS 7 create a bottom UIToolbar like Photo and AppStore

Tags: ios, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I would like to create a bottom `UIToolbar` on iPad like Photo and AppStore apps. A taller toolbar whit custom `UIBarButtonItem` with image above text.
The problem is that I can't resize the 44px height in the .xib and if I try to change frame programmatically doesn't work.

Ideas ?

[image]
[image]

**Edit**

I want replace this interface with `UIToolbar` because the tab bar behavior is not what I need : I don't have many view controllers, but only functionalities that I want call from `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: use UITabbar you can adjust image inset and title .

Comment: You can also just make a customised tabbar yourself with a normal UIView and some buttons shaped just the way you want.

Comment: See the edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Image** with your **logo** and **text** in it, assign it to a custom `UIButton` and assign it to `UIBarButtomItem` using `initWithCustomView`

```
UIImage *customImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourCustomImage"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, customImage.size.width, customImage.size.height);
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourCustomImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPreviousView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

Hope this helps You..

Comment: where did backButton come from? Did you mean customBottom?: `backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, customImage.size.width, customImage.size.height);` Also, doesn't UIButton put the text on the side rather than on the bottom?